# How do I run a command on all files in a folder (which has sub-folders) using ExifTool?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, exiftool

I have a folder called **Photos & Videos**.
It has folders for the various years for which I have photos and videos.
The year folders have folders for months and the months folders have folders for the days of that month.
The days folders contain all my image and video files.

Now, I want to run commands on all these files using one single exiftool command.

For example, to remove the metadata of all files in a folder, I'm running this type of command on every single day folder one at a time.

```
exiftool -all= -overwrite_original Documents/Personal/Photos\ \&\ Videos/2015/3-2015/7-3-2015/ .
```

The problem is I have too many days folders.
So, is there a way I can target all the files in the Photos & Videos folder all at the same time using one single command.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-r` to your command.  `-r` will recuse into all the subdirectories.

Comment: I'm a noob to shell scripting. Can you tell me where exactly do I put -r in the command?

Comment: Exiftool is very flexible about where to put option commands.  But to keep things simple, stick it near the beginning, someplace before the filepath, e.g. `exiftool -r -all= -overwrite_original`

Comment: Adding -r didn't seem to work on the specified folder. Instead it started stripping metadata off other files in some other folder. I used this command on a test folder on the desktop which has three sub-folders.  `exiftool -r -all= -overwrite_original Desktop/test/ .`

Comment: Are you including the dot in your command?  The dot indicates the current directory, so in the command you posted above, it would attempt to process two directories.  Unfortunately, I don't know much about osx but I believe you can drag the folder onto the terminal to get the correct path.  So type or paste the command, add a space, then drag the folder onto the terminal window.  Don't add the dot unless you actually want to process the current directory.

Comment: Oops! My fault. I've removed the dot and it works like a charm now :D Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution that will work for all commands is to use `find`.

`find Documents/Personal/Photos\ \&\ Videos/2015/3-2015/7-3-2015/ -type f` will print out every file in `Documents/Personal/Photos & Videos/2015/3-2015/7-3-2015`.  To run a command on each of those files, you can use the `-exec` parameter, with an admittedly odd syntax:

```
find Documents/Personal/Photos\ \&\ Videos/2015/3-2015/7-3-2015/ -type f -exec exiftool -all= -overwrite_original '{}' \;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I've integrated the accepted answer already in my workflow.  But, I'll try out your suggestion as well :)

Comment: While this may be the only thing to do for some programs, this is not something you want to do with exiftool and is very rarely needed due to exiftool's flexibility.  Startup is one of the biggest performance hit for exiftool and looping and running it individually over each file can significantly increase run time.  See [Improving Performance](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#performance).

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know.